# SSD temperature sensor readout with hddtemp

Tags: ssd, temperature

It seems hddtemp cannot detect the temperature sensor of my SSD (Samsung EVO 840) properly.This is the bash output when running hddtemp:

```
WARNING: Drive /dev/sda doesn't seem to have a temperature sensor.
WARNING: This doesn't mean it hasn't got one.
WARNING: If you are sure it has one, please contact me (hddtemp@guzu.net).
WARNING: See --help, --debug and --drivebase options.
/dev/sda: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 120G B              @:  no sensor
```

I looked in the most recent .db file posted on http://nongnu.mirrors.hostinginnederland.nl//hddtemp/hddtemp.db, but it doesn't seem to list any SSD drives at all.

Was anyone able to readout the temp-sensor of a SSD with hddtemp?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry but I can't comment...anyway

`Hddtemp` usually reads field `194` from the smart data of the hard disk but in this case the info from the sensor is stored in field `190`. With that command you tell `hddtemp` to read the value of field `190` for that particular model.

To check:

```
smartctl -a /device

hddtemp --debug /device
```

In both cases field 190 shows the temperature of the hard disk, (eg. 190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel)

Answer (score 9):

Can confirm previous answers for Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS also and "Samsung SSD 850 EVO 1TB". (but there is not the mentioned space needed in drive label)

So, what to do?

1. In case the drive is unknown to hddtemp:

   check the drive's SMART data output for temperature sensor data and look for the field "ID#"

   > `$ sudo smartctl /dev/sdb -a | grep -i Temp`
   >
   > `190 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   111   104   000    Old_age   Always       -       36`

   The very first field is the sensors attribute id#, "190" in this case.
2. add an entry into hddtemp's db, located at /etc/hddtemp.db

   > `$ sudo echo "Samsung SSD 850 EVO 1TB" 190 C "Label for SSD 1TB" >> /etc/hddtemp.db`

   - field 1: use a string or regex matching the drive's display name (as reported by hddtemp output)
   - field 2: SMART data field number (190 in this case)
   - field 3: temperature unit (C|F)
   - field 4: label string / comment
3. now hddtemp knows how to read the data

   > `$ sudo hddtemp /dev/sdb`
   >
   > `/dev/sdb: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 1TB: 40°C`

Comment: Wondering why I get some garbage characters in the output: `root@digger:/etc# hddtemp
/dev/sda` yields  `Samsung SSD 850 EVO 120G B              ▒@: 35 C`

Answer (score 5):

```
root@elmo:/etc# hddtemp 
WARNING: Drive /dev/sda doesn't seem to have a temperature sensor. 
WARNING: This doesn't mean it hasn't got one. 
WARNING: If you are sure it has one, please contact me (hddtemp@guzu.net). 
WARNING: See --help, --debug and --drivebase options. 
/dev/sda: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 120G B              ▒@:  no sensor
```

insert into `/usr/share/misc/hddtemp.db` this line:

```
"Samsung SSD 850 EVO 120G B"                            190  C  "Samsung SSD 850 EVO 120GB"
```

now `hddtemp` shows temperature

```
root@elmo:/etc# hddtemp
/dev/sda: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 120G B              ▒@: 47 C
```

Comment: You should not provide a translation for the German output in the question in your answer. Propose an edit to the question instead and remove it here. Thank you! :)

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS the database path is `/etc/hddtemp.db`

Comment: Same for 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo echo '"Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250G B" 190 C "Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB"' >> /etc/hddtemp.db
```

Worked to me, but there needs to be space between "250G" and "B" like "250G B" not "250GB".

Comment: If space needs then why you didn't include in command?

Comment: maybe is 190 C a bit hot?

Answer (score -1):

Do:

```
sudo echo '"Samsung SSD 840 EVO 120G B" 190 C "Samsung SSD 840 EVO 120GB"' >> /etc/hddtemp.db
```

Comment: Can you explain what this command does?

Comment: i understand this command adds my SSD to the database file so i do not get a "not in database" error any more... but my problem is i cannot read out the sensor in the first place, its value is not readable by hddtemp although i there is one built in.